# How to multiply sparse matrices using hmatrix

Tags: haskell, matrix-multiplication

I've got a matrix `m` of dimension `3329×3329` with lots of zero fields and I want to calculate `m^9`.
After trying this with the `matrix` package (`Data.Matrix` is easy to use) I figured that a sparse matrix would make a better representation of this in terms of memory usage and possibly also computation speed. So I'm trying to figure out how to use the `hmatrix` package. I've already managed to create a sparse matrix:

```
module Example where

import Numeric.LinearAlgebra as LA

assocExample :: AssocMatrix
assocExample = [((0,0), 1),((3329,5),1)]

sparseExample :: GMatrix
sparseExample = LA.mkSparse assocExample
```

My problem at this point appears to be that I've got a `GMatrix`, but for the multiplication operator `(<>)` I need a `Matrix t` instead.
By looking trough the [hmatrix](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) documentation on hackage I didn't manage to figure out how to obtain a `Matrix t` here.

I've also had a quick gaze at the [introduction to hmatrix](http://dis.um.es/~alberto/material/hmatrix.pdf) but the term `sparse` isn't even mentioned in it.

My hunch is that this should be easy enough to do, but I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparse matrices are to my knowledge rather young in hmatrix. Looking through the docs it seems there is no product of sparse matrices. You must implement it yourself.

Edit: And if you done so, comment here: https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix/issues/162 (also substantiates my statement above)

Comment: Hey thanks - I'll investigate this a bit and than likely accept your answer. This possibility didn't even occur to me ^^